# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. React JS Error while mapping component

Tags: reactjs

Here is my React code to render Navbar:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import {Nav,Form,Button,FormControl,NavDropdown} from 'react-bootstrap';
export default function NavigatorHeader(props)
{
    return(
        <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg" style={{ width: 400 }}>
                <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="mr-auto">
                        {props.Header.map(element=>{
                            <Nav.Link href={element.href} key={element.id}>{element.title}</Nav.Link>
                        })}
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
    );
}
```

Here is my pros.Header:

```
Headers:[
        {
            id:0,
            title:"Projects",
            href:"#home"
        },
        {
            id:1,
            title:"Events",
            href:"#home"
        },
        {
            id:2,
            title:"Achievements",
            href:"#home"
        },
        {
            id:3,
            title:"Skillsets",
            href:"#home"
        },
    ]
```

I am trying to map this like this:

```
<Navbar bg="light" expand="lg" style={{ width: 400 }}>
                <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="mr-auto">
                        {props.Header.map(element=>{
                            <Nav.Link href={element.href} key={element.id}>{element.title}</Nav.Link>
                        })}
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
```

I get the following error: "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression." Does anyone know where exactly I am going wrong? I want to map and create multiple such items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a return statement before the <Nav.Link.

```
{props.Header.map(element=>{
                    return <Nav.Link href={element.href} key={element.id}>{element.title}</Nav.Link>
                    })}
```